# Save image to a specific photo album with photo framework ios 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, photo

I have just created a new photo album with this code:

```
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^
     {
         //Checks for App Photo Album and creates it if it doesn't exist
         PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
         fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", @"ChameleonSensors"];
         PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:fetchOptions];

         if (fetchResult.count == 0)
         {
             //Create Album
             PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:@"ChameleonSensors"];
         }

     }

      completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Log here...");

         if (!success) {
             NSLog(@"Error creating album: %@", error);
         }else{
             NSLog(@"Perfecto");
         }
     }];
```

This is ok, but now I need to save photos in this photo album.

I´m using objective-c and photo framework.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add assets to albumRequest

```
    //Create Album
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:@"ChameleonSensors"];
    PHAssetChangeRequest *createImageRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"]];
    [albumRequest addAssets:@[createImageRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset]];
```

Comment: Is it possible to know the path where that image was saved?,

Comment: Yes, a placeholderForCreatedAsset always has the same local identifier as the asset, collection, or collection list that it represents. To find the object that corresponds to a placeholder, read the placeholder’s localIdentifier property and use it to fetch the actual object.

Comment: I have obtained this identifier: 9C41BF95-A9C5-498B-AFFA-6D9CF6B56C21/L0/001. Is it that correct?, now How can i obtain the path?

Comment: the only way i found is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28879226/2463852) . use `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:` and get `fullSizeImageURL` from `PHContentEditingInput`